# In my angular 14.0.6, the ngx-echart is not working in nested child module component

Tags: angular, ngx-echarts

In my application, there is a app.module  under that page.module and then dashboard.module.

Whenever i am tring to use ngxechart for component inside dashboard.module its giving error i.e

Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.:

<div id="chart" echarts [options]="echartMapOption" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;background-color: bisque;"></div>

I have tried multiple solution.Its working fine in app.component but not in child module component.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether NgxEchartsModule is imported in  app.module.ts?

```
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';
```

Comment: Yes, its already imported in app.module.ts.  
Maping in app.module.ts: 
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';

 NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
      echarts: () => import('echarts')
    }),

Comment: Instead of `NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({ echarts: () => import('echarts') })` try this `NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({ echarts })`
[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-ngx-echarts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) is a working example, please refer to whether all the imports you made are correct.

Comment: Still Not working for nested module component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 15, you need install ngx-echarts@15.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Place the component where eCharts is used
in the `NgModule` declarations:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       *yourComponent*
    ]
})
```